# Set images to the cells used NSArray from urls, but it doesn't work

Tags: ios, image, url, nsarray, collectionview

i have try to create a simple photo browser, and i used UICollectionView, when i try to insert them thumb images to the cell, it does't work,it has a thread, but i can't fixed it,please help me, thank you very very much. here is my code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView   cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ImageCell";
ImageCell *cell = (ImageCell *)[collectionView     dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSArray *images =    @[@"http://www.example.com/p1.jpg",@"http://www.example.com/p2.jpg",@"http://www.example.com/p3.jpg",@"http://www.example.com/p4.jpg"];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:images[indexPath.row]];

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use SDWEBIMAGE. thus you can use

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your image url"]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

[see this link](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

Comment: If it`s helpful to you then Upvote it for others refrence :) cheers

Comment: BTW,if i want add an images link array ,what should i do, i need insert many url images to the thumbs cell,

Comment: You can set images to the UIIMAGE and Fill your array with that UIIMAGE. Then give it to the your cell`s ImageView.

Comment: i dont understand how to do,can't you tell me,please help me.

Comment: Get Your number of url`s into any array. Then [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Yourarray objectatIndex:IndexPath.Row] ]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

Comment: If it`s Give you Idea about how to do it, then you can accept my answer!

Comment: yes,I will, and my code is:'- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ImageCell";
    ImageCell *cell = (ImageCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    NSArray *images = @[@"http://www.example.com/p1.jpg",..];

    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    return cell;
}'but it has a thread.

Comment: it seems okay.. Now whats the issue??

Comment: it bas a thread on the NSArray *images = @["images array urls"],what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You have to same or more number of objects in that array then number of rows in your TableView.

Comment: Alloc init your Array at out of cellForItemAtIndexPath method. i.e. feed your images array in your ViewDidLoad method.